# pronoun after adjective

Tags: personal-pronouns

[image]

In this picture, what is the usage of the pronoun "you"?
Can we use "subject pronoun" after "adjective",as in the picture "a different you".

Comment: A pronoun is a word that takes the place of a noun. You can use it as in the picture because originally it's a word and this is a place for a noun. It sounds perfect to me. Plus there is no other way to say this with the same emphasis on "you"

Answer (score 5):

Advertising, exhortations, and other rhetorical texts often make a point of employing unusual constructions in order to seize your attention and make their points more memorable.

There's nothing ungrammatical in modifying pronouns. It's uncommon, because the ordinary use of a pronoun is to refer as briefly as possible to something previously identified. Here, however, *you* doesn't mean just the person addressed but the changeable nature of the person addressed: "a different you" means you as you might be, a person with different characteristics than you now possess.

This is, by the way, not a "subject pronoun" but an "object pronoun": *you* does not distinguish subject and object forms, but *you* here is the Direct Object of the verb *demand*.

Comment: [The younger me](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+younger+me%22) would seem to be far more popular than [the older me](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+older+me%22). I put that down to the fact that the former has often helped me to learn from his mistakes, but the latter remains unhelpfully silent even when he knows perfectly well that what I'm thinking about doing isn't going to work out too good!

Answer (score 0):

The gist is that to get to the next level you need to grow your talents. If you keep performing at the same level then you'll be stuck at your current level.

The reason for the "your" and "you" is so that the message would apply to any person. So to apply to me, Max:

**Every next level of Max's life will demand a different Max.**